# How to get values in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array

I want to collect all the movie id's where in rating is above 3 from the below array

```
let movies = [
  {'name': 'Actions', 'movies': [{'id': 1, 'rating': 2}, 
                                 {'id': 2, 'rating': 1}, 
                                 {'id': 3, 'rating': 4}]},
  {'name': 'Comedy', 'movies': [{'id': 4, 'rating': 3}, 
                                 {'id': 5, 'rating': 4}, 
                                 {'id': 6, 'rating': 5}]},
  {'name': 'Sci-fi', 'movies': [{'id': 7, 'rating': 1}, 
                                 {'id': 8, 'rating': 5}, 
                                 {'id': 9, 'rating': 2}]}
];
```

I'm getting the id's with rating above 3 from below code

```
let res = movies
          .map( m => m.movies
                    .filter( f => f.rating > 3 ) 
          )
          .flat();
console.log(res);
```

output

```
[[object Object] {
  id: 3,
  rating: 4
}, [object Object] {
  id: 5,
  rating: 4
}, [object Object] {
  id: 6,
  rating: 5
}, [object Object] {
  id: 8,
  rating: 5
}]
```

How can i get rid of `[object Object]` and `rating` from my output and get only flatted id's array?

Answer (score 2):

Flatten the movies to an array using `Array.flatMap()`, filter by the `rating`, and then map to `id`s:

```js
const movies = [{"name":"Actions","movies":[{"id":1,"rating":2},{"id":2,"rating":1},{"id":3,"rating":4}]},{"name":"Comedy","movies":[{"id":4,"rating":3},{"id":5,"rating":4},{"id":6,"rating":5}]},{"name":"Sci-fi","movies":[{"id":7,"rating":1},{"id":8,"rating":5},{"id":9,"rating":2}]}];

const result = movies
  .flatMap(m => m.movies)
  .filter(m => m.rating > 3)
  .map(m => m.id);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `forEach()` loop:

```js
const movies = [{
  "name": "Actions",
  "movies": [{
    "id": 1,
    "rating": 2
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "rating": 1
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "rating": 4
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Comedy",
  "movies": [{
    "id": 4,
    "rating": 3
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "rating": 4
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "rating": 5
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Sci-fi",
  "movies": [{
    "id": 7,
    "rating": 1
  }, {
    "id": 8,
    "rating": 5
  }, {
    "id": 9,
    "rating": 2
  }]
}];

let result = [];

movies.forEach(({movies}) => {
  var movie3 = movies.filter(({rating}) => rating > 3).map(({id}) => id);
  result = [...result, ...movie3];
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Which is just a "complicated" way of `.map()`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired output by adding map(rw => rw.id) after flat function.

```
let res = movies
          .map( m => m.movies
                    .filter( f => f.rating > 3 ) 
          )
          .flat().map(rw => rw.id);
console.log(res);
```